Strategy when deprecating 3rd party cookies in favour of tokens
This question is more so theoretical, but my project is in Rails, in case someone wants to show a concrete example.
We have a SAAS application, where I expect customers to be logged in to myapp.com.
The app has a widget, that can be accessed at http://www.myapp.com/widget
Most importantly, it can be embedded on to different platforms in an iFrame:
<iframe src="myapp.com/widget"></iframe>

Previously, when customers were already logged in to myapp.com, the iFrame seamlessly loaded up, because the cookies were stored in the browser, and automatically sent with the /widget http request.
Since 3rd party cookies are deprecated, we are replacing them with an Access Token that is stored in Session Storage on the browser.
This is perfectly fine in 99% of cases, as we simply add the header Authorisation: Bearer {token_from_session_storage} to all outgoing API requests within the widget.
This can be achieved with some client middleware on our HTTP library (e.g. Angular interceptors).
However, the initial loading of the iFrame in the src will fail authentication, and we can't do anything like:
<iframe src="http://myapp.com/widget" headers="Authorization={token}"></iframe>


What is the cleanest strategy to solve this problem?
For customers who use the widget, we want a seamless transition, i.e. ideally they won't need to change any iFrame code.
So if there is a backend-first strategy, that would be ideal.
